# Primeng inputMask autoClear not working as per documentation

Tags: angular, primeng

As per document invalid input should not clear on using autoClear="false" but it is not working.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputmask

```
  <p-inputMask  autoClear="false" styleClass="form-control custom-input" placeholder="User phone number"
                        formControlName="phoneWork" maxlength="14" mask="(999) 999-9999"></p-inputMask>
```

Comment: Try: `[autoClear]="false"`

Comment: It worked I am very new to angular .. What difference it made by using [autoClear]?

Comment: I think you should read the entire question and answer before reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried by adding `"` to `autoClear="false"`?

Or maybe with `[autoClear]="false"`?